# Dataframe filled with random numbers based on user input of columns and rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Create a program that has a function that takes two integer arguments and prints a Pandas dataframe.  The two arguments will correspond to the number of rows and number of columns, respectively.  The dataframe should be filled with random integers from 0 to 100.  Set your random seed to 56.

So this is what i  have so far:

```
import random

import pandas as pd


data1 = random.seed(56)

arg1 = int(input('a number1:'))

arg2 = int(input('a number2:'))

df = pd.DataFrame(data1, arg1, arg2)

print(df)
```

it prints a data frame with 2 rows and columns and fills them with the numbers the user inputs. Any help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [create a dataframe from user inputed columns and rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65921906/create-a-dataframe-from-user-inputed-columns-and-rows)

Comment: This is quite literally a duplicate of a question you yourself asked recently. If you do not receive an answer that satisfies your question you should place a bounty on the question when you have enough rep. Reasking an identical question to get additional attention is an inappropriate use of stack overflow

Comment: Sorry about that i completely forgot i even asked it after i went out on my own and tried it again after letting it sit for a day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your code `data1` is the output of `random.seed(56)` and does not depend on user input at all. I think you want:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

arg1 = int(input('a number1:'))

arg2 = int(input('a number2:'))

# set the seed
np.random.seed(56)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100, size=(arg1, arg2)))
print(df)
```